# VMWare Win7 guest on Win7 host can't access internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, vmware

I have a Win7 guest on VmWare Workstation 6.5 running on another Win7 that is on a notebook with wireless network. Seeking this same problem on web pages I do not found and answer for my problem not even a problem like mine.

I tried Bridge or Nat, changing windows network adapter confs on the two OS, and change settings on Virtual Network Editor too. But none worked.

My notebook ip is something like 192.168.1.170, gateway is 192.168.1.1. Even setup virtual adapters to this subnet and this configs on DHCP not worked. My great doubt is what type of connection to use on VM (Bridge, NAT, etc...) and what adapter to change (VMNet0, VMnet8) or create a new one.

I don't know how to combine those options to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

I use Custom VMnet8(NAT) on the Virtual Machine.

In the Workstation "Virtual Network Editor" set

Tab NAT/ VMnet host = VMnet8.

Tab DHCP/ Virtual Network = VMnet8

Quit and restart Vmware after Workstation network setting changes; if not sometimes they do not work properly.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work.

Comment: of course VMnet8 has to have the DHCP service enabled on the "virtual network editor" ... If it doesn't work tell us what the client's ipconfig parameter returns

Comment: Nope. Ipconfig returns this: ipv4: 192.168.1.245 and gateway 192.168.1.1, that's is our router.

Comment: I consider your internet comes from the wireless connection, then there's no way the guest OS could ever hit your wireless DHCP service for getting its IP. Are you having some "bridging" enabled?? I recommend you starting over reading the settings on my answer carefully.